# Looking to delete a list item from an array of items after fetching list data from REST API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to delete a list item from a group of list items that I obtain dynamically from a REST API. I can delete the list item from the BACKEND with an axios request just fine, but i have to refresh the page in order for the actual list item display to no longer show. I'm trying to just delete the list item from the UI so that when I press delete, it will both delete on the backend and the frontend. Can't seem to figure it out and I've tried quite a few different ways.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      loading: false,
      value: '',
      open: false
    };

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }

  search = async val => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    let res = await search(
      `https://zuul-stage.whatifops.com/v1/user/phone/${val}`
    );
    this.setState({ users: res, loading: false });
  };

  onChangeHandler = async e => {
    this.search(e.target.value);
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  };

  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      open: !this.state.open
    });
  }

  get renderUsers() {
    let users = <h1 />;
    if (!this.state.loading) {
      users = this.state.users.map(user => (
        <div>
          <Row>
            <Col lg={2} style={{ maxWidth: '9.7%' }}>
              <Button
                color='danger'
                style={{ paddingTop: 12, paddingBottom: 12 }}
                onClick={this.toggle}
              >
                <i className='fa fa-trash'></i>&nbsp; Delete
              </Button>
            </Col>
            <Col lg={10}>
              <ListGroup>
                <ListGroupItem key={user.id} value={user.value} id={user.id}>
                  <strong>Email:</strong> {user.email} &nbsp; &nbsp;
                  <strong>Phone:</strong> {user.phone}
                </ListGroupItem>
              </ListGroup>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <br />
          <Modal
            isOpen={this.state.open}
            toggle={this.toggle}
            className={'modal-danger'}
          >
            <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggleSuccess}>Delete User</ModalHeader>
            <ModalBody>
              <Row>
                <Col
                  lg={2}
                  style={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    color: '#f86c6b'
                  }}
                >
                  <i className='fa fa-warning fa-3x'></i>
                </Col>
                <Col lg={10}>
                  Are you sure you want to delete the user with the following
                  credentials:
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <span>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{' '}
                    <strong>
                      <i className='fa fa-envelope'></i> &nbsp;Email:
                    </strong>{' '}
                    {user.email}
                  </span>
                  <br />
                  <span>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{' '}
                    <strong>
                      <i className='fa fa-phone'></i> &nbsp;Phone:
                    </strong>{' '}
                    {user.phone}
                  </span>
                </Col>
              </Row>
              <br />
            </ModalBody>
            <ModalFooter>
              <Button color='danger' onClick={this.open}>
                Delete
              </Button>
              <Button color='secondary' onClick={this.open}>
                Cancel
              </Button>
            </ModalFooter>
          </Modal>
        </div>
      ));
    } else {
      return <p>Loading...</p>;
    }

    return users;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className='display-4'>Users</div>
        <hr />
        <Row>
          <Col lg={12}>
            <Label>Enter an email or phone number:</Label>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col lg={12}>
            <Input
              value={this.state.value}
              onChange={e => this.onChangeHandler(e)}
              placeholder='Begin typing to search'
            />
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <br />
        {this.renderUsers}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Any and all would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Updated code:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      loading: false,
      value: '',
      open: false
    };

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }

  search = async val => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    let res = await search(
      `https://zuul-stage.whatifops.com/v1/user/phone/${val}`
    );
    this.setState({ users: res, loading: false });
  };

  onChangeHandler = async e => {
    this.search(e.target.value);
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  };

  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      open: !this.state.open
    });
  }

  onDelete(e) {
    let id = e.target.id;
    let updatedUsers = this.users.filter(user => user.id != id);
    this.setState({ users: updatedUsers });
  }

  get renderUsers() {
    let users = <h1 />;
    if (!this.state.loading) {
      users = this.state.users.map(user => (
        <div>
          <Row>
            <Col lg={2} style={{ maxWidth: '9.7%' }}>
              <Button
                color='danger'
                style={{ paddingTop: 12, paddingBottom: 12 }}
                onClick={this.onDelete(user.id)}
              >
                <i className='fa fa-trash'></i>&nbsp; Delete
              </Button>
            </Col>
            <Col lg={10}>
              <ListGroup>
                <ListGroupItem key={user.id} value={user.value} id={user.id}>
                  <strong>Email:</strong> {user.email} &nbsp; &nbsp;
                  <strong>Phone:</strong> {user.phone}
                </ListGroupItem>
              </ListGroup>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <br />
          <Modal
            isOpen={this.state.open}
            toggle={this.toggle}
            className={'modal-danger'}
          >
            <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggleSuccess}>Delete User</ModalHeader>
            <ModalBody>
              <Row>
                <Col
                  lg={2}
                  style={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    color: '#f86c6b'
                  }}
                >
                  <i className='fa fa-warning fa-3x'></i>
                </Col>
                <Col lg={10}>
                  Are you sure you want to delete the user with the following
                  credentials:
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <span>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{' '}
                    <strong>
                      <i className='fa fa-envelope'></i> &nbsp;Email:
                    </strong>{' '}
                    {user.email}
                  </span>
                  <br />
                  <span>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{' '}
                    <strong>
                      <i className='fa fa-phone'></i> &nbsp;Phone:
                    </strong>{' '}
                    {user.phone}
                  </span>
                </Col>
              </Row>
              <br />
            </ModalBody>
            <ModalFooter>
              <Button color='danger' onClick={this.open}>
                Delete
              </Button>
              <Button color='secondary' onClick={this.open}>
                Cancel
              </Button>
            </ModalFooter>
          </Modal>
        </div>
      ));
    } else {
      return <p>Loading...</p>;
    }

    return users;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className='display-4'>Users</div>
        <hr />
        <Row>
          <Col lg={12}>
            <Label>Enter an email or phone number:</Label>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col lg={12}>
            <Input
              value={this.state.value}
              onChange={e => this.onChangeHandler(e)}
              placeholder='Begin typing to search'
            />
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <br />
        {this.renderUsers}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you want to delete the user from this.state.users, you can something like this

```html
onDelete(id){
let updatedUsers = this.users.filter(user=>user.id!=id)
this.setState({users:updatedUsers })
}
```

you need to add an id to each user if already don't have.

My suggestion would once you made an API call only delete it from the frontend if its a success so you can add this code in API success call back. So, if the delete call fails don't delete it on the front end either

```
onClick={() => this.onDelete(user.id)}
```

this is how you should attach onDelete

Comment: i'm getting an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined, because the user is undefined until it grabs it from the API. any error checking i could do?

Comment: once you created the list you should have the user data can you share the updated code I can debug it

Comment: updated the answer since you are already passing the id to the function you don't need to get it from event.target. let me know if this works

Comment: that's funny, i actually did the same thing at the same time lol! yes, this worked thank you :)

Comment: awesome happy to help

Answer (score 0):

js as i was having the same issue, this works to only show related services to the service we are currently viewing.

```
const useData = () => {
    let getIndex;
    return (getIndex = data.filter((card) => {
      return card.node.slug !== router.query.slug;
    }));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setCardData(useData);
  }, [router.query.slug]);
```